# SwiftUI ButtonStyle - how to check if button is disabled or enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

To style a button in SwiftUI, according to my understanding, you extend `ButtonStyle` and implement `func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View` within which you start applying modifications to the `configuration.label` which is a reference to the `Button` view.

Now, besides the `label` field, `ButtonStyle.Configuration` has a boolean field for `isPressed`, but that's seems to be all.

How do I check if the button is enabled or disabled?

For example, I want to draw a border around the button, and I want the border to be blue if the button is enabled and gray if disabled.

My first guess is something like this:

```
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(configuration.isEnabled ? Color.blue : Color.gray, lineWidth: 1).padding(8)
            )
    }
```

But there's no `isEnabled` field.

The Apple-supplied `PlainButtonStyle` obviously has access to this information, as the doc comment in the header file that declares it says 'The style may apply a visual effect to indicate the pressed, focused, or enabled state of the button.'

```
/// A `Button` style that does not style or decorate its content while idle.
///
/// The style may apply a visual effect to indicate the pressed, focused,
/// or enabled state of the button.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct PlainButtonStyle : PrimitiveButtonStyle {
.....
```

Is there a way to access this information?

### EDIT:

Before you suggest closing this question, please read this:

There's a similar question asked a while ago. That question does not specify any context.

Here I have a specific context: creating a generic reusable button style.

The answer provided there does not suffice. I can't expect people to pass the disabled state to the style constructor. That's too much duplication of effort.

Can you imagine if people have to write code this way:

`Button() { .... }.disabled(someExprssion).buttonStyle(MyCustomStyle(disabled: someExpression))`

Clearly that's not desireable.

Also clearly the Apple supplied style has access to the information without requiring people to pass the disable state again to the style.

If you close the question, you will forever prevent anyone from providing a useful answer to this question on StackOverflow.

Please reconsider before you propose closing.

### EDIT2:

I have a guess that if you can get the `EnvironmentValues.isEnabled` of the `Button` view then it might be the right value.

So another way to ask the question is: is it possible in SwiftUI to get the environment of a view that you didn't define yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know if a SwiftUI Button is enabled/disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849090/how-can-i-know-if-a-swiftui-button-is-enabled-disabled)

Comment: that suggests there's no way, but clearly there is a way since the builtin PlainButtonStyle knows?

Comment: As expected, the close  police started raiding ..

Comment: When creating a new struct NewButtonStyle: ButtonStyle, it seems that it's not possible to grab the button's @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled. Only got to access the correct value of isEnabled when creating a custom Button...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to this blog: https://swiftui-lab.com/custom-styling/

You can get the enabled state from the environment by creating a wrapper view and using it inside the style struct:

```swift
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        MyButton(configuration: configuration)
    }

    struct MyButton: View {
        let configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration
        @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled: Bool
        var body: some View {
            configuration.label.foregroundColor(isEnabled ? Color.green : Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

This example demonstrates how to get the state and use it to change the appearance of the button. It changes the button text color to red if the button is disabled or green if it's enabled.

Comment: I had to use @SwiftUI.Environment because I had the error "Enum 'Environment' cannot be used as an attribute"

Comment: Yea I expect as time goes on and Swift changes, some of the keywords here will have to change ..

Comment: For anyone who comes recently, there's no need to do such contraption anymore, you can simply put the @Environment line in the ButtonStyle struct and it will be honoured.

Comment: @MichelDonais can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva look at Jonathan.'s answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69134893/1060383

Comment: @michelDonasi not if you're supporting iOS 13.0.. it will crash when referencing it

Comment: No longer the best answer.

Comment: @hasen would you like to make the newer solution the accepted answer?

Answer (score 42):

You can access the enabled value through environment directly in the ButtonStyle, eg:

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(!isEnabled ? Color.black : (configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.blue))
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not if you're supporting iOS 13.0

Answer (score 10):

Tweaked up a bit on @hasen answer so as to make things more configurable

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var foreground = Color.white
    var background = Color.blue
    
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        MyButton(foreground: foreground, background: background, configuration: configuration)
    }

    struct MyButton: View {
        var foreground:Color
        var background:Color
        let configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration
        @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled: Bool
        var body: some View {
            configuration.label
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 7.0, leading: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, trailing: 7.0))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .foregroundColor(isEnabled ? foreground : foreground.opacity(0.5))
                .background(isEnabled ? background : background.opacity(0.5))
                .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
       Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Hello")
        }.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(foreground: .white, background: .green))
```

Comment: does not seem to be working on macOS

Answer (score 8):

Answering your question: yes, it is possible to get the `Environment` value you didn't pass yourself. `SwiftUI` uses the `Environment` heavily and a lot of `View`s depend on it without you even knowing it.

**A `ButtonStyle` can access `Environment`** too so you can achieve what you want as easy as:

```
struct SomeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .disabled(!self.isEnabled)
            .opacity(self.isEnabled ? 1 : 0.5)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working in iOS15, but not iOS14.3. Looks like a bug in the operating system. Do you have this issue?

Comment: This feels like the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to pass a `disabled` Boolean value to your `ButtonStyle`, and then use the `allowsHitTesting` modifier on the label to effectively disable the button:

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let disabled: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .allowsHitTesting(!disabled)
    }
}
```

Comment: best solution so far

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the disabled status into the buttonStyle, so that you will not used it twice in the application.

```
  struct CustomizedButtonStyle : PrimitiveButtonStyle {

var disabled: Bool = false

func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
configuration.label.disabled(disabled)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(disabled ? Color.blue :  Color.gray, lineWidth: 1).padding(8)
    )
}
}


 struct ButtonUpdate: View {
 var body: some View {
    VStack{
    Button(action: {
    }) { Text("button")
    }.buttonStyle(CustomizedButtonStyle(disabled: true))
    Button(action: {
    }) { Text("button")
    }.buttonStyle(CustomizedButtonStyle())
    }}

  }
```

Comment: sounds like a reasonable work around but then the style is not really just a style anymore and can't be easily replaced with other styles. at this point might as well use a custom button instead of the builtin `Button`

Comment: bro what is your formatting

Answer (score 0):

we have to use  @Environment(.isEnabled) it should check button is enabled or disabled and you can also change the background colour if disabled

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonStyling:ButtonStyle {

    @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .bold()
            .padding(.all,5)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
            .background(isEnabled ? Color("AppButtonBackground"): Color("AppButtonBackground").opacity(0.5))
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

And use this like

````
private var isFormValid: Bool {
          !packageName.isEmpty && duration > 0
      }

     Button {
                                    
                                } label: {
                                    Text("Save")
                                        .buttonStyle(ButtonStyling())
                                        .disabled(!isFormValid)
                                }
    
    ```
````