# Button won't show disabled styling

Tags: swiftui

I made a struct that styles my buttons by passing a type and size parameters. I would like the button to change style when it's disabled, but it's not working. The button does toggle between disabled and enabled, but the style is always the enabled style.

```swift
struct CustomButton: ButtonStyle {
    
    enum ButtonStyle {
        case button, destructive, light
    }
    enum ButtonSize {
        case normal, large, small
    }
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled
    private var maxWidth : CGFloat
    private var padding : CGFloat
    private var foreground : Color
    private var foregroundDisabled : Color
    private var strokeColor : Color
    private var strokeDisabled : Color
    private var strokeWidth : CGFloat
    private var background : Color
    private var backgroundDisabled : Color
    private var fontSize : Font
    
    init(style: ButtonStyle, size: ButtonSize) {
        switch size {
        case .large:
            self.maxWidth = .infinity
            self.padding = 15.0
            self.fontSize = Font.system(.title3, design: .rounded).weight(.bold)
        case .small:
            self.maxWidth = 200
            self.padding = 8.0
            self.fontSize = Font.system(.callout, design: .rounded)
        default:
            self.maxWidth = .infinity
            self.padding = 12.0
            self.fontSize = Font.system(.body, design: .rounded)
        }
        
        switch style {
        case .light:
            strokeColor = .main
            strokeDisabled = .gray
            strokeWidth = size == .small ? strokeSmall: strokeLarge
            foreground = .main
            foregroundDisabled = .gray
            background = .clear
            backgroundDisabled = .clear
        case .destructive:
            strokeColor = .destructive
            strokeDisabled = .gray
            strokeWidth = size == .small ? strokeSmall : strokeLarge
            foreground = .destructive
            foregroundDisabled = .destructive
            background = .clear
            backgroundDisabled = .clear
        default:
            strokeColor = .clear
            strokeDisabled = .clear
            strokeWidth = 0.0
            foreground = .white
            foregroundDisabled = .white
            backgroundDisabled = .gray
            background = .main
        }
    }
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        return configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth)
            .font(fontSize)
            .foregroundColor(isEnabled ? foreground : Color.red)
            .padding(padding)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: roundedCorner)
                .strokeBorder(isEnabled ? strokeColor : strokeDisabled, lineWidth: strokeWidth)
                .background(isEnabled ? background : backgroundDisabled)
            )
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: roundedCorner))
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1.0)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.98 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

And it's added to a view like this:

```swift
Button(action: {   
   //Some logic here
}, label: {
    Text(NSLocalizedString("Add Group", comment: "button"))
})
.disabled(selections.count < 2) //the button does become disabled (but doesn't change style)
.buttonStyle(CustomButton(style: .button, size: .normal))
```

Comment: Would this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169436/swiftui-buttonstyle-how-to-check-if-button-is-disabled-or-enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @Environment is not injected in style, it is only for views, so here a demo of possible solution - based on internal helping wrapper view.

```
struct CustomButton: ButtonStyle {

    enum ButtonStyle {
        case button, destructive, light
    }
    enum ButtonSize {
        case normal, large, small
    }

    private var maxWidth : CGFloat
    private var padding : CGFloat
    private var foreground : Color
    private var foregroundDisabled : Color
    private var strokeColor : Color
    private var strokeDisabled : Color
    private var strokeWidth : CGFloat
    private var background : Color
    private var backgroundDisabled : Color
    private var fontSize : Font

    init(style: ButtonStyle, size: ButtonSize) {
        switch size {
        case .large:
            self.maxWidth = .infinity
            self.padding = 15.0
            self.fontSize = Font.system(.title3, design: .rounded).weight(.bold)
        case .small:
            self.maxWidth = 200
            self.padding = 8.0
            self.fontSize = Font.system(.callout, design: .rounded)
        default:
            self.maxWidth = .infinity
            self.padding = 12.0
            self.fontSize = Font.system(.body, design: .rounded)
        }

        switch style {
        case .light:
            strokeColor = .main
            strokeDisabled = .gray
            strokeWidth = size == .small ? strokeSmall: strokeLarge
            foreground = .main
            foregroundDisabled = .gray
            background = .clear
            backgroundDisabled = .clear
        case .destructive:
            strokeColor = .destructive
            strokeDisabled = .gray
            strokeWidth = size == .small ? strokeSmall : strokeLarge
            foreground = .destructive
            foregroundDisabled = .destructive
            background = .clear
            backgroundDisabled = .clear
        default:
            strokeColor = .clear
            strokeDisabled = .clear
            strokeWidth = 0.0
            foreground = .white
            foregroundDisabled = .white
            backgroundDisabled = .gray
            background = .main
        }
    }

    private struct EnvReaderView<Content: View>: View {    // << this one !!
        let content: (Bool) -> Content
        @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled  // read environment
        var body: some View {
            content(isEnabled)  // transfer into builder
        }
    }

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        EnvReaderView { isEnabled in    // now we can use it !!
            configuration.label
                .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth)
                .font(fontSize)
                .foregroundColor(isEnabled ? foreground : Color.red)
                .padding(padding)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: roundedCorner)
                                    .strokeBorder(isEnabled ? strokeColor : strokeDisabled, lineWidth: strokeWidth)
                                    .background(isEnabled ? background : backgroundDisabled)
                )
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: roundedCorner))
                .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1.0)
                .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.98 : 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```